# How does this app access GMail?

Tags: android, gmail

I'm writing an Android app that needs to access GMail, and I'd like to do it the same way the SwiftKey does, by showing the user a (Google-hosted?) prompt to login to their Google account, like this:

[image]

Do you know what API they're using to get this prompt? Does this API provide direct access to GMail or do I still have to use IMAP?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like oauth being handled via webview which is constructed to look like dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Intent` for your requirement. Following is the code for same.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
i.setType("text/plain"); 
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{ "target@gmail.com"}); 
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject"); 
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body part"); 

try 
{     
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Sending  Email...")); 
} 
catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) 
{     
   Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "No Email clients",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show(); 
}
```

This code will allow you to communicate via Gmail Server.